# "showmodaldialog" not working in chrome! Any alternatives other than window.open?

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-11, showmodaldialog

In my code, "showmodaldialog" has been used for datepicker, but it is not working in chrome!

Any alternatives other than window.open?

One another thing, as I am working under IE11 changes, this change needs to run on all three, chrome, IE11 STD mode and IE9 STD mode.

Comment: If this is an enterprise app where you control the clients, you can re-enable `showmodaldialog` via a Chrome policy setting, see http://blog.chromium.org/2014/07/disabling-showmodaldialog.html 

If you're trying to deploy this on the public Internet, then you'll need to rewrite the code if you need it to work on Chrome. I support their decision BTW.

Answer (score 0):

Use [JQuery modal](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) for other browsers.  For more details study JQuery